# Wicket web application: session timeout

Tags: java, web-applications

I have a web application Spring based that works with Wicket. I have a problem with **session**: I cannot set the session timeout. How can I do this? I tried to set it in `web.xml` file but it doesn't work.

```xml
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: Neither Spring, nor Wicket manages the session timeout. This setting is managed by the web container. Which container do you use (Tomcat, Jetty, ...) ? And how the rest of the application is setup (in web.xml or via Java configuration) ?

Comment: We are using Tomcat like web container, and we are using the web descriptor web.xml for the configuration of the web application settings. Perhaps we use WicketApplication.java to make some setting in the Wicket configuration.

Comment: Why do you think that it doesn't work? What do you expect and what actually happens?

Comment: I tried with a session-timeout of 1 minute and i see it doesn't work. I think at the timeout would be redirect to the login page setting in WicketApplication.java
    getApplicationSettings().setPageExpiredErrorPage(LoginPage.class);

Comment: It will redirect only if your application has security setup. Otherwise Wicket will just create a fresh instance of the current page. Better use HttpSessionListener to check whether the session is invalidated.